# how to add progress bar in python using tqdm

Tags: python, copy, progress-bar

I have a script that list files and directories and copy the required one. Now i need to add a **progress bar** to display the progress of the copy using **tqdm package**

The problem is that i do not know where to make the iteration for the **tqdm** in order to get the result i want.

code:

```
numfile = len(files)
for  file in files:
            full_file_name = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            if os.path.join(dirpath) == src:
                if file.endswith("pdf"):
                    if not os.path.exists(dst2):
                        os.mkdir(dst2)
                    else:
                        print("the path alredy exist")
                     shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst2)
                    i+=1
                    
                elif file.endswith("docx") or file.endswith("doc"):
                     shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst)
                    j+=1

            elif os.path.join(dirpath)== src2:
                if file.endswith("pdf"):
                     shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst3)
                    z+=1
        
         for z in tqdm(range(numfile)):
            sleep(.1)

        print("*******number of directories = {}".format(len(dirnames)))
        print("*******number of files = {}".format(len(files)))
```

For now it copy the files  than it display the progress bar.

What i want is to display the progress bar while copying

Comment: [all the SO answers about adding a progress bar](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+how+to+add+progress+bar+with+tqdm+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk01XP-2xRh9h3zhpp-QJVJXAnkzkTQ:1593031542772&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi05eP5qJvqAhUVPH0KHfFxDecQrQIoBDAAegQIBRAN&biw=1920&bih=975)

Comment: why not just wrapping files in the second line with tqdm?

Comment: @MercyDude what you mean ?

Comment: why not just changing the second line to "for file in tqdm(files):"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tqdm` to track the progress of your outer loop.

```py
for file in tqdm(files):
    # Copy file
```

In your current code, the progress bar is only showing your progress in sleeping for `numfiles`/10s. This is meaningless and causes your code to sleep for `numfiles`/10s every time you copy a file.